# Rstudio hangs when loading XLConnect

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm getting a hang in RStudio when I try and load XLConnect. It works find when I try from the same R console outside RStudio.

i.e. in RGui (64-bit)

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

> library(XLConnect)
Loading required package: XLConnectJars
XLConnect 0.2-11 by Mirai Solutions GmbH [aut],
  Martin Studer [cre],
  The Apache Software Foundation [ctb, cph] (Apache POI, Apache Commons
    Codec),
  Stephen Colebourne [ctb, cph] (Joda-Time Java library)
http://www.mirai-solutions.com ,
http://miraisolutions.wordpress.com
```

But when I run in Rstudio the same R console hangs. I've confirmed that rJava loads so I think I have my Java environment correct

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

> library(XLConnect)
Loading required package: XLConnectJars
```

Appreciate any thoughts on what the issue is - it works fine on my laptop so not sure what's different

Regards
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an Rstudio issue fixed in the latest version - I updated Rstudio to 0.99.491 (from an earlier 0.99.x release but not sure the version) and it now works fine.

edit - although it sometimes still appears to hang but eventually the package loads?